# The special function $\beta(1/2,u,1-u).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, beta-function, sturm-liouville

If $u\in\mathbb{N}$ then following identify is established as an exercise in substitution
$$
(-1)^{u+1}\beta\left(\frac{1}{2},u,1-u\right)=\log 2-\mathfrak{X}_{u-1}\exp(-\psi_{u-1}) \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
Here $\beta$ is the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), $\mathfrak{X}_{u-1}$ is the numerator of the $(u-1)-$th alternating harmonic number and $\psi_{u-1}$ is the logarithm of the least common multiples of the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,u-1.$ Indeed if we allow $u\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ and plot the LHS of $\ref{a}$ in the Cartesian plane then we see that the zeros of the LHS of $\ref{a}$ occur whenever $u=1/2+k$ for every natural number $k.$ See the graph below. The LHS of $\ref{a}$ can be expressed as the hypergeometric function:
$$
g_{u}\text{ }_{2}F_{1}\left(u,u;1+u;\frac{1}{2}\right)  \label{b}\tag{2}
$$
where $g_{u}:=(-1)^{1+u}(1/2)^{u}(1/u).$ It is known that $\ref{b}$ satisfies the second order linear differential equation
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}+\left[1+u-(u+u+1)\frac{1}{2};\right]\frac{dw}{dz}-u^{2}w=0 
$$
; which after simplifying is the equation
$$
\frac{d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}+2\frac{dw}{dz}-4u^2w=0 \label{c}\tag{3}
$$

> **Question**: Is equation $\ref{c}$ correct? If not what is the correct calculations?

I also think it is fair to ask what is the eigenvalue problem with respect to the Sturm Louiville form of $\ref{c}.$ Note I have the Sturm-Louiville form as:
$$
\frac{dw}{dz}\left[\exp(2z)\frac{d}{dz}\right]-4\exp(2z)u^2w=0
$$

---

[image]

Comment: (2) does not depend on $z$. I assume you meant that when $1/2$ is replaced by $z$, then it satisfies equation (3).

Comment: @gary - embarrassingly I cannot follow your comment.  However  (2) was set up by direct substitution from the [hypergeometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation). I took $z=1/2$.  Writing the LHS of (1) as (2) can be found as an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_cases)

Comment: You write "It is known that 2 satisfies the second order linear differential equation" and present a differential equation where derivation is taken with respect to $z$. But 2 does not depend on $z$. This is what I meant.